# Retrieving array of json objects stored in couchbase document | spring

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

How do I retrieve an array of JSON objects stored in a couchbase document and store it in its respective list, say `List<ProjectSummary>` using `spring-data`?

Below is the content of the document named 'project-summary' on couchbase -

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "New API",
        "owner_id": "dsdssdsd445d",
        "description": "Yh A Testin API",
        "status": "unactiveAPI"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "New TW Projec API",
        "owner_id": "dsdssdsd445d",
        "description": "Testin API",
        "status": "unactiveAPI"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Projec API",
        "owner_id": "dsdssdsd445d",
        "description": "Testin",
        "status": "unactiveAPI"
    }
]
```

When I try to retrieve it using as follows-

```
public interface ProjectSummaryRepository extends CrudRepository<List<ProjectSummary>, String>{}

//within main method
Optional<List<ProjectSummary>> summaries = projectSummaryRepo.findById(COUCHBASE_DOCUMENT_ID);
```

i get an exception saying -

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.CouchbaseList cannot
>   be cast to
>   org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.CouchbaseDocument

I have annotated my document class as below -

```
@Document
public class ProjectSummary implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String title;
    @Field
    private String owner_id;
    @Field
    private String status;
    @Field
    private String description;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **findById** can't be used in this scenario. You have to use SpringData DSL to query your data:

```
public interface ProjectSummaryRepository extends CrudRepository<List<ProjectSummary>, String> {

   //using standard Spring Data DSL
   List<ProjectSummary> findByTitleAndStatus(String title, String status)

   //complex query using N1QL syntax
   @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and status = $1 and ( title  = $2 or owner_id = $3)")
   List<ProjectSummary> findWithSomeComplexQuery(String status, String title, String owner_id)
 }
```

After that you can simply call those methods inside your code;

```
  List<ProjectSummary> sumaries = projectSummaryRepo.findByTitleAndStatus("someTitle", "someStatus")

  List<ProjectSummary> sumaries2 = projectSummaryRepo.findWithSomeComplexQuery("someStatus", "someTitle", "owner123" )
```

Comment: I tried using standard spring dsl (List<ProjectSummary> findById(String id)) but it gave me this error message - "No index available on keyspace project-summary-bucket that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online."

Comment: You have to create at least a primary index for your bucket first. Run "create primary index on YOUR_BUCKET_NAME" on your couchbase server https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/createprimaryindex.html